# how to prevent google apps script trigger if a function is already running

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a trigger which runs an apps script function every 5 minutes. Sometimes, maybe 1 in 10, the function takes over 5 minutes (but less than 6) to run. If this is the case, I do not want the trigger to run the function again because it will be repeating what is currently being done. I want it to wait another minute and then run. How can I check if the function is running and use this to allow or disallow the trigger? Also notice that my script mostly runs around 3 or 4 minute mark (the very short entries are a different function) so if I could be more efficient and trigger again sooner if it finishes early, that would be amazing.

[image: statii]

Answer (score 4):

Put a value into Cache that lasts 10 minutes.
At the end of the code, remove the Cache property.
When the code runs, try to get the value out of cache, if it's there, then quit.
I'd use Cache Service instead of Properties Service because if the code fails and the value in Properties Service doesn't get changed or deleted, then you're code could stop running altogether.  Cache will timeout at the set time regardless of whether the code completes or not.

```
function myCode() {
  var isItRunning;

  isItRunning = CacheService.getDocumentCache().put("itzRunning", "true",600);//Keep this value in Cache for up to X minutes
  //There are 3 types of Cache - if the Apps Script project is not
  //bound to a document then use ScriptCache
  if (isItRunning) {//If this is true then another instance of this
    //function is running which means that you dont want this
    //instance of this function to run - so quit
    return;//Stop running this instance of this function
  }

  //Put the code you want to run here

  CacheService.getDocumentCache().remove("itzRunning");
  
}
```

Comment: this would double my running time though when I'm looking to reduce it. Why cant there just be a way to query the deployment status?

Comment: This does not double your running time.  The Cache time out value that I suggested of 10 minutes doesn't have any effect on when your code actually stops running.  The Cache timeout value, is a count down timer for when the value in Cache is no longer kept in memory.  Cache is a temporary storage service.  It's not permanent, like Properties Service.  Also, if your code completes, then the Cache value is removed, so at that point the timeout value in seconds is immaterial, it's gone.

Comment: I'm not understanding why it's not working for me. The bit of code I want to run goes between the if statement and the cacheservice statements, right? The 600 equals 10 minutes? My triggers keep running and they aren't stopping.

Comment: The code you want to run does not go into the "if" statement, it goes after the "if" statement. I've updated the answer with notes.

Comment: Keep in mind Cache stores and retrieves STRING values - not boolean values

Comment: you should check the value from get() instead of put()

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "Flag" variable with values representing if a Trigger is running or not and store the value using Properties or Cache. `'1' = A trigger is running` OR `'0' = No trigger is running`

```
function myTrigger() {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  // Waits until last trigger is already done
  while(scriptProperties.getProperty('flag') == '1')
    Utilities.sleep(60000);
  
  // Once started set flag value as '1'
  scriptProperties.setProperty('flag', '1');

  // Your code...

  // Once finished set flag value as '0'
  scriptProperties.setProperty('flag', '0');
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to query Deployment == head, status == running .

Comment: So if my code is 

myfunc()
for(i = 1 to length, i++) url fetch (html); do something

Instead I will have 

yourfunc()
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); etc.

 for(i = 1 to length, i++) url fetch (html); do something

  scriptProperties.setProperty('flag', '0'); etc.
}

And have the trigger pointing to yourFunc?

Please confirm! This would be perfect because I could set a trigger to 1 minute and be super efficient

Comment: I see you updated your question, and there is a failed execution, so I would recomend to better use Cache instead of Properties as in Alan Wells answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the trigger and create a new one that will wait 5 minutes at the end of each execution.

You can check the [Managing triggers programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) to delete and create new triggers.

This is an example of it:

```js
function myFunction() {
  //Execute function
  Logger.log('executed');

  //Delete trigger
  var oldTrigger = ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers()
  for (var i = 0; i < oldTrigger.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(oldTrigger[i]);
      break;
  }

  //Create new trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, when I create a 5 minute trigger it waits 5 minutes before it will run. This will not prevent the trigger "going off" while the other function is running if it takes 5 minutes 45 seconds or something longer than 5 minutes. The plan is to check the head status and if it's running - dont trigger, wait a minute (or something).

Comment: You can move the delete trigger part at the start of the execution, that way here will be no trigger anymore and the execution will be able to run the minutes it needs without having to worry on another execution starting. When the execution finishes, a new trigger is created and it will run 5 minutes after the creation. If you want it to run one minute later, you can change ehr `everyMinutes` part.

Comment: There is a quota of creating 20 triggers per user per script.  So after the trigger had been deleted and then a new one created 20 times, then you will hit the quota, and your code will stop working.  When the code runs every 5 minutes, that 12 times an hour.  So in an hour and 40 minutes you will hit the trigger quota and if you can't create a new trigger then your code will stop working altogether. [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)